# Adding GWT visualization library?

Tags: java, gwt

I am trying to import the gwt-visualization library into my java project. I downloaded API in a folder called gwt-visualization-1.1.2.zip. I unzipped it and now I don't know what to do with the files. Is there a place in my Eclipse program files where I should move the gwt-visualizations.jar file?

I have put this in my .java file...

```
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.AbstractDataTable;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.VisualizationUtils;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.DataTable;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.Selection;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.AbstractDataTable.ColumnType;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.events.SelectHandler;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.visualizations.PieChart;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.visualizations.PieChart.Options;
```

And this in my .xml file...

```
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.visualization.Visualization'/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just include gwt-visualizations.jar in your project's build path.

1. Go to Properties of your project
2. Navigate to Java Build Path
3. Go to the tab Libraries
4. Find the button 'Add External JARs..'
5. Add visualizations jar